# Autocorrelation and spectral density in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, correlation

This question is threefold.

We have an LTI system that is a first degree Butterworth LP filter with the power TF

[image]

where `fu = 110Hz` and `f1 = 90Hz`

The input `X(t)` has the autocorrelation: `R_X(\tau) = 5e^{-600|\tau|}`

1) How can I calculate the power spectral density of the output in MATLAB? FFT? How do I represent the autocorrelation as a vector?

2) How can I simulate the system and plot the output in MATLAB?

3) I am also supposed to write a matlab function that returns samples of the time-domain function as $X(n*\Delta t)$, $n=0,1,..,N$ where $\Delta t = 1/f_s$ and $f_s = 2000Hz$.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't a complete answer, but it will help you get started. To get the power spectral density of the output, find the Fourier transform of $R_x(\tau)$ and multiply it by $\vert H(f)\vert^2$. I'm not sure what you mean by representing the autocorrelation as a vector. It's a function of $\tau$, so you could create a vector of autocorrelation values by just evaluating it at a series of values of $\tau$. For instance,

```
tau = -10:0.01:10;
R_x = 5*exp(-600 * abs(tau));
```

To simulate, suppose that `x` is the function you are interested in and that it takes in a value for time and returns the value of the function, something like this (of course 'x' is a horrible name for a function, but this is all for illustration purposes):

```
function y = x(t)

% code to calculate the value of the function at time t

end
```

Then we could see what the filter does with something like this:

```
T = 100;      % Duration of the signal (s).
fs = 500;     % Sampling frequency (Hz).
t = 0:1/fs:T;  % Vector of time samples (s).

% Frequencies used to define the filter's response.
fu = 110;
f1 = 90;

% The size of the FFT.
Nfft = 2^nextpow2( length(t) );

% The sample locations of the FFT. This assumes
% the FFT has been shifted.
f = fs*(-0.5 : 1/Nfft : 0.5-1/Nfft);

% Evaluate the function at the give time values.
% We also shift to put DC in the middle.
X = fftshift( fft( x(t), Nfft ) );

% This is the squared response of the filter.
Hsqd = 1 ./ ( 1 - ( (f.^2 - fu*f1) ./ (f*(fu-1)) ) );

% Plot power of the filtered signal.
plot( f, X .* conj(X) .* Hsqd );
```

Double check the above for errors though since I haven't actually run it.

Comment: Wow thanks, this helps a bunch. But one thing I don't clearly understand is how I can get samples of the time-domain signal $X(t)$. All that is given is the autororrelation function (from which we could obtain the PSD). I see I missed that in the original post; I am also supposed to write a matlab function that returns samples of the time-domain function as $X(n*\Delta t)$, $n=0,1,..,N$ where $\Delta t = 1/f_s$ and $f_s = 2000Hz$.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that. There might be a way that I learned in school, but if so, I never used it and have forgotten it. Are you supposed to recognize the form of $R_x(\tau) = a e^{b \vert \tau \vert }$? Does it look like any examples/problems you have had to do?

Comment: @user2750354 I think you are supposed to recognize that the autocorrelation of transient exponential is another transient exponential and be able to derive the time-domain representation from it. Have you tried calculating the autocorrelation function of $a e^{-b t}$?